# Access button from View in ViewModel in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, openfiledialog

I am trying to access a button from `View` in `ViewModel`, but I am missing something as I get the error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Loadfile' and no extension method 'Loadfile' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Uml-Creator C:\Users\HH\Source\Repos\UMLEditor\Uml-Creator\Uml-Creator\View\MainWindow.xaml 54  Active
```

The purpose of the button is to open a `OpenFileDialog`. In my `ViewModel` I handle the click like this:

```
class Load
    {

        private void Loadfile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog loadfile = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (loadfile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //  File.Text = File.ReadAllText(loadfile.FileName);
            }
        }
}
```

And the View:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

```
<Button x:Name="openButton" ToolTip="Open project" Click="Load_Click">
                    <Image  Source="pack://application:,,,/Images\Open.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="17"></Image>
                </Button>
```

Comment: How is your `xaml` defined?

Comment: You are violating the concept of MVVM. Your viewmodel shouldn't know anything about your view. If you want to have behaviour in your viewmodel you should use ICommand

Comment: It seems that the DataContext of your View is not set to your `Load` class.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal It's large, but I have put the button in my main window

Comment: @GalDak: only your button.

Comment: @GalDak you should head to google and enter "wpf mvvm tutorial" and potentially add button to the query. clearly you are at the very beginning of learning mvvm

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Have edited the OP

Comment: @GalDak: Given my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In `MVVM` architecture, View and ViewModel are loosly coupled. You should use Command like `DelegateCommand` and set `DataContext` of View as instance of ViewModel like this

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new Load();
}
```

In XAML do something like

```
<Button .... Click = "{Binding ClickCommand}" />
```

Use Nuget to get Prism Packages and in Load Class, use DelegateCommand like

```
public Load
{    
    public DelegateCommand<object> _clickCommand;
    public DelegateCommand<object> ClickCommand    
    {
       get
       {
           if (_clickCommand == null)
               _clickCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnClickCommandRaised);
           return _clickCommand;
       }
    }

    public void OnClickCommandRaised(object obj)
    {
        //Your click logic.
    }
}
```